# Python Function and function calling problem

Tags: python, function

I am trying to find the prime numbers with these function. When I return it; the output prints;

`"Prime Number"` and the number I inputted

```
number=int(input("Please enter the number :"))

def my_function(number):
  if number==1:
   print("Not a Prime Number.")
  elif number==2:
   print("Prime Number")
  for i in range(2,number):
    if number%i==0:
     print("Not a Prime Number")
     break
    elif number%i!=0:
     print("Prime Number")
     break
  return number

print(my_function(number))
```

Comment: At the end i just need the text "Not a Prime Number" or "Prime Number"

Answer (score -1):

```
print(my_function(number))
```

In this statement, you are printing whatever is being returned from the function `my_function` and you are returning the input number from `my_function`.

Instead of the above statement, just use the call my_function directly as below:

```
number=int(input("Please enter the number :"))

def my_function(number):
  if number==1:
   print("Not a Prime Number.")
  elif number==2:
   print("Prime Number")
  for i in range(2,number):
    if number%i==0:
     print("Not a Prime Number")
     break
    elif number%i!=0:
     print("Prime Number")
     break
  return number ### You are returning the number here.

my_function(number) #Just don't print the return value here
```

Just don't print the value returned from `my_function` and it should solve your problem.

Comment: But when i run your code i get nothing in the screen because we don't print anything

Comment: I have edited the code based on your complete code. Try now.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend, let me ask you something i am beginner at functions , how could we run the code without print ?

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't understand your question. What do you mean by without print?